# Set value in $_POST variable to validate through Codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I'm creating the WebSocket based application with Codeigniter. So, data is coming as a JSON string(not a POST Method). I want to use the Codeigniter's built-in form_validation method to validate the data received as JSON.

this is what I tried so far to set the variable so I can access it through `$this->input->post('variable_name')` but.

**Try #1**

```
$_POST['variable_name'] = !isset($data['variable_name']) ? NULL : $data['variable_name'];
```

**Try #2**

```
$variable_name = !isset($data['variable_name']) ? NULL : $data['variable_name'];
$this->form_validation->set_value("variable_name", $variable_name);
```

But when I use `$this->input->post('variable_name')`
it returns `NULL`.

Comment: If I remember currectly, CI Input class extracts all the data from the post and caches it in an internal variable, so when you use $this->input->post you are getting values from that cache. That means, that you need to alter the Input class, or set the data to the $_POST array before CI loads.

Comment: If so, its a strange behaviour. There should be a way to set values manually. :(

Comment: Not really, it makes sense - your POST data should not change from the moment your script starts.

Comment: so, what do you recommend?

Comment: is there any other way of validation using Codeigniter?

Comment: @RonDadon Here is the `post` method from codeigniter input class.

`public function post($index = NULL, $xss_clean = NULL)
 {
  return $this->_fetch_from_array($_POST, $index, $xss_clean);
 }`
It uses `$_POST` (global) parameter.

Comment: what version of CI are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how I achieved it. Although, It doesn't seems to be an accurate solution but its simple and there is no work around.

I added only one line before execution of form validations

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] = "POST";
```

and then set the variable like this

```
$_POST['post_var'] = "value";
```

Now set the validation rules and perform validation.

that's it :)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks. :)

Comment: You got the answer, that's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 6):

There's a method called `set_data()` that was introduced specifically to allow validation of non-POST inputs.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post

Comment: This should be the chosen answer.